# How to search specific index names from Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

In my ES cluster, I'm having indices like, 'movies-2011', 'movies-2012', 'movies-2013' ...
I want to fetch the indices list which starts from "movies..".
Are there any ways to achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ES Documentation Link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cat-indices.html)

**Try below:**

```
GET /_cat/indices/movies*
```